# Id of added entity is not yet set within SaveChangesInterceptor

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, interceptor

Using `SaveChangesInterceptor` I am setting information about added, edited, removed entities and their properties. Unfortunately PK is not set yet so I end up with values close to -2^31. How can I get the final Id?

```
  public class CustomInterceptor : SaveChangesInterceptor
    {
        public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var context = eventData.Context;
            [...]
            if (property.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey()) // If it is newly added entity ID is not yet final
                    {
                        auditEntry.KeyValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        continue;
                    }
            [...]
            return base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Then I end up with this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean by `final ID`? `SavingChanges` is called *before* the Save operation. `SavedChanges` is called after the operation. If the ID value is generated by the database, only `SavedChanges` will be able to retrieve it

Comment: How come the primary key is a JSON string instead of a bigint? Did you try to change the `ID` property to a "value object" ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think this is some kind of audit/logging table so to support all possible scenarios (composite keys, different key types) keys are treated as dict and dumped as json.

Comment: @GuruStron Correct.